# How to get JSON in bottle(python framework) from a Jquery script

Tags: python, jquery, json

I'm sending a POST request containing JSON data using AJAX Jquery. And supposed to receive it to my API server, which is written in bottle. However, the json is sent from the client side, but doesn't seem to be received by the server.
The jquery function gets the data from an html form. and that's working perfectly. I believe the problem is in the communication between the JS code and python code.
I've been looking at similar questions and problems for hours, almost all of them are solved by setting the content-type to "application/json", this, however, didn't work for me.

```
$("#add_pro").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
    var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
    var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
    var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for 
                                      submission

    //Send the data of the added item to the server
    $.ajax({
        url : post_url,
        type: request_method,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data : form_data,
    })
 });
```

And here is what I have for the server side:

```
@post('/db-example/add')
def add(db):

item = request.json

db.execute("INSERT INTO supermarket (product, origin, amount, image, best_before_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",(item['product'], item['origin'], item['amount'], item['image'], item['best_before_date']))

lastProduct = db.execute("SELECT * FROM supermarket WHERE product=?", (item['product'],)).fetchall()

return json.dumps(lastProduct)
```

The error I'm getting is:
    TypeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'",)
And when I try to print request.json, the output is NONE.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem I see is that you are asking for the JSON and then expecting it to behave like a dict.  `request` already converts the post fields into a dict for you. Below I am giving you a trick to take a post with either query parameters or input fields and merging them into a usable dict.

```
@post('/db-example/add')
def add(db):

    item = dict(request.forms).update(dict(request.query.decode()))

    db.execute("INSERT INTO supermarket (product, origin, amount, image, 
    best_before_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",(item['product'], item['origin'], 
    item['amount'], item['image'], item['best_before_date']))

    lastProduct = db.execute("SELECT * FROM supermarket WHERE product=?", 
    (item['product'],)).fetchall()

    return json.dumps(lastProduct)
```